# Detect when actions are created, handler best practices?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to figure out the best way to detect when actions are created on an object, so I can better organize them. I know there's no observer pattern-style way to subscribe to specific changes, but I do know that I can use a handler (`depsgraph_update_post` now, in 2.8x?) to hook into the core update function in Blender.

If the situation is still anything like the questions I found on this topic from 2013-2017, the update hook will call whatever callback I append to it 2000 times a second. I don't need anything near that fast, though I noticed there are also timers hanging out in `bpy.app`, with some caveats about using them to make updates due to threading concerns. Are timers that update every second a better way of avoiding the issues with `depsgraph_update_post`'s intense loop speed?

Also, somewhat unrelatedly, I noticed that if keyframes are added to an object, that object's action isn't created until after the action editor context is moused over. Is there a way to skip that step, and add actions the moment keyframes are created for an object?